# Auto tap/click on element of other app android

Tags: android, click, element, rooted-device

I'm a manual tester and now I want to automation testing. I wan to create an app to execute some actions like press button on target app test. It looks like app auto click but in my case, it finds location button by id/text, not fixed coordinate because app test must be run on more device with another screen size.
Is possible with my app? And if possible, please help me with the demo. Thank you.

Comment: If you have access to the code, you can try the Espresso Test Recorder.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have apk only. :(

Comment: Did you try to search some APK testing tool?

Comment: Yes, I tried some auto click app, but all of them only use static coordinate. And some testing automation library I tried require access code, it beyond my capabilities.